# How to send email from gitlab docker machine build

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this process on gitlab with the following yaml file:

```
variables:
 DOCKER_IMAGE: "registry.commandcentral.com/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}/project-    name-e2e-tests/${CI_BUILD_ID}"
 DOCKER_IMAGE_REF: "registry.commandcentral.com/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}/project-name-e2e-tests:${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}"

  before_script:
 - echo $DOCKER_IMAGE
 - echo $DOCKER_IMAGE_REF

stages:
 - build
 - e2e
 - notify:slack

build docker:
  stage: build
tags:
  - shell
script:
  - docker build -t ${DOCKER_IMAGE} .

.e2e-template: &e2e-template
  stage: e2e
  tags:
    - shell
  only:
    - develop
    - release

  script:
    - JOB_NAME=( $CI_BUILD_NAME )
    - SERVICE_NAME=${JOB_NAME[1]}
    - docker build -t ${DOCKER_IMAGE} .
    - docker run ${DOCKER_IMAGE} npm run   e2e:${SERVICE_NAME}:${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}

 e2e project: *e2e-template
 e2e projec2: *e2e-template

notify slack on build failure:
  stage: notify:slack
  when: on_failure
  only:
    - develop
    - release

  image: url.domain.com/krk-devops/slack-notifier:develop
  tags:
    - dind
  script:
    - slack-notify build-failed project
```

This basically runs the e2e tests for a project using protractor (selenium webdriver framwork, which uses external selenium-grid). After such tests are run the folder is created with .html report with screenshots.

The goal I want to achieve is to be able to send an email with that folder attached if the build fails, or (mayby first to start with on every execution). Any ideas how to achieve that from that docker machine ?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?